# Does WCF Polling Duplex Binding exist for non Silverlight clients?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-binding

Does WCF Polling Duplex Binding exist for non Silverlight clients?

Comment: Hi Alex, any pointers for somebody looking for the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to implement your own Binding.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a AJAX sample here http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/09/scale-out-of-silverlight-http-polling.html